# Display Json array after post - autcomplete

Tags: json, curl, autocomplete

Hi I am doing jQuery post to my file where I have curl which has to fetch php array then I am parsing it as JSON when it comes back as succes.

But I cant see it as array inside script tags.
I need to do Autocomplete on this json array but it doesnt append in the array. Please help, code below. Code as it self works, e.g. but I dont know how to implement autocomplete.

/*Here is curl*/

```
if ($_POST['function'] == 'cities')
{
///Cities - WORKING 

$ch = curl_init('URL - works');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Accept: application/json')
);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($result);
}
```

AND HERE /*post where I want to have JSON array from which I want to autocomplete */

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.post( "assets/curls.php",{ function: 'cities'}, function( data ) {

                var result = array();
                result = $.parseJSON(data);

      });     
</script>
```

What I want to accomplish is to have in result - json array:

result = [city:{New York, Oklahoma, Marakesh}];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to create answer for this by combining autocomplete with jQuery post, autocomplete has results from POST:

```
$.post( "assets/curls.php",{ function: 'cities'}, function(data) {
              var result = $.parseJSON(data);
  $("#usr").autocomplete({source: result});
});
```